# Bluetooth "br-connection-profile-unavailable" issue on upgrade to Xubuntu 23.04

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, xfce

Recently I upgraded from Xubuntu 22.04 to Xubuntu 23.04 using the Software Updater. Aftert upgrading, Bluetooth doesn't connect to either any of the previously paired devices or to any new device. The error displayed is: `br-connection-profile-unavailable`

Specs:

Xfce 4.18
  GTK version: 3.24.37
  Kernel version: 6.2.0-25-generic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using Debian 12 . Ran into this problem. Trying fixes from different forums didn't help. Finally switched to pipe wire as bluetooth sound server following instructions from this : https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp

1st removed pulseaudio-module-bluetooth.
Then installed libspa-0.2-bluetooth.
Restartred system.
My wireless bluetooth headphone is working fine now. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Joy Chakraborty.

Comment: In my case didn't have to remove anything. Just installed package, then restarted pipewire.

Answer (score 7):

What solved it for me was:

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

Comment: Great solution. Worked pretty well for me too.