# Troubleshooting Bluetooth Connection Issue with Unbranded AirPods on Lenovo Ideapad S-145

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, lenovo, realtek

I'm experiencing a persistent Bluetooth connectivity issue with my unbranded air pods when trying to use them with my Lenovo Ideapad S-145. Previously, they connected seamlessly to both my mobile device and laptop. However, after a recent use of my mobile phone, the air pods no longer maintain a stable connection to my laptop's Bluetooth. They connect for a brief moment (1-2 seconds) before disconnecting.

In an attempt to resolve this, I installed `bluez`, but this did not rectify the problem. When trying to connect, I encounter the error `br-connection-profile-unavailable`. My research led me to a solution involving restarting `pulseaudio` via `systemctl` ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479606/bluetooth-br-connection-profile-unavailable-issue-on-upgrade-to-xubuntu-23-04)), but this approach has not yielded a permanent fix. Additionally, I occasionally experience issues with YouTube videos not playing unless I restart `pulseaudio`.

I am seeking advice on the following:

1. Possible causes for this Bluetooth connectivity issue.
2. Steps to resolve the `br-connection-profile-unavailable` error.
3. Any related insights into the intermittent issue with YouTube playback?

Thank you for your assistance.